# react-router-dom > 6 useParams() inside class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

An error occurred on `ShowBookDetails.js`

*Error*

> ShowBookDetails.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
> at ShowBookDetails.componentDidMount (ShowBookDetails.js:16:1)
> at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23305:1)
> at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24688:1)
> at commitLayoutEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24674:1)
> at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:24612:1)
> at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26823:1)
> at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:26682:1)
> at finishConcurrentRender (react-dom.development.js:25981:1)
> at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25809:1)
> at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:1)

*ShowBookDetails.js*

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from "axios";

class ShowBookDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            book: {}
        };
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5050/api/books/' + this.props.match.params.id)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    book: res.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("Error from ShowBookDetails")
            })
    }

    onDeleteClick(id) {
        axios
            .delete('http://localhost:5050/api/books/' + id)
            .then(res => {
                this.props.history.push("/");
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("Error form ShowBookDetails_deleteClick");
            })
    };


    render() {
        const book = this.state.book;
        let BookItem = <div>
            <table className={"table table-hover table-striped table-bordered"}>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Title</td>
                    <td>{book.title}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>Author</td>
                    <td>{book.author}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>ISBN</td>
                    <td>{book.isbn}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">4</th>
                    <td>Publisher</td>
                    <td>{book.publisher}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">5</th>
                    <td>Published Date</td>
                    <td>{book.published_date}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">6</th>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td>{book.description}</td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>

        </div>
        return (
            <div className={"ShowBookDetails"}>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-10 mx-auto">
                            <Link to="/" className={"btn btn-outline-warning float-left"}>Show Book List</Link>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
                            <h1 className="display-4 text-center">Book's Record</h1>
                            <p className="lead text-center">
                                View Book's Info
                            </p>
                            <hr/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {BookItem}
                    </div>

                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg btn-block"
                                    onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this, book._id)}>Delete Book
                            </button>

                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <Link to={`/edit-book/${book._id}`} className="btn btn-outline-info btn-lg btn-block">
                                Edit Book
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ShowBookDetails;
```

*App.js*

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Routes,  Route} from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import CreateBook from "./components/CreateBook";
import ShowBookList from "./components/ShowBookList";
import ShowBookDetails from "./components/ShowBookDetails";
import UpdateBookInfo from "./components/UpdateBookInfo";

class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<ShowBookList/>} />
            <Route path={'/create-book'} element={<CreateBook/>} />
            <Route path={'/edit-book/:id'} element={<UpdateBookInfo/>} />
            <Route path={'/show-book/:id'} element={<ShowBookDetails/>} />

        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The short answer is to not use class components anymore (or wrap the class component in a functional one that uses the hook and passes along the props).

Comment: Could you update the code snippet?

Comment: It seems like you are angry!

Comment: You could say that, yes

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Wrapped from functional, I show code:

```
const WrappedShowBookDetails = props => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return <ShowBookDetails id={id} {...props} />;
}
```